# How to resolved SQL syntax error by using entity in spring boot?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

I have this order entity. When I use an API to save order, it has this error:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order (address, created_date, email, full_name, guid, phone_number, price, usern'`

I don't know why it has an error. My schema still working alright. Please help me!

```java
@Entity(name = "order")
public class Order {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "order_id")
    @Id
    private int id;

    private String guid;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "full_name")
    private String fullName;

    private String address;

    @Column(name = "phone_number")
    private String phoneNumber;

    private String email;

    private double price;

    @Column (name = "created_date")
    private Date createdDate;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "order")
    private List<OrderProduct> listProductOrders = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

Comment: `I don't know why it has an error.` - order is a reserved word in SQL context and it should be quoted

Comment: kindly print full exception trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

order is a reserved word you need to provide a different name to your table.

Comment: Then I must rename the table "order". :sosad:

Comment: No other option, faced the same issue :)